# ActiveRecord: "uuid-ossp" extension added, but no uuid functions available

Tags: postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, postgresql-extensions

Using `rails-5.0.7.1` (according to `bundle show rails`)

I wrote a migration which adds the `"uuid-ossp"` extension, and the SQL gets executed, and the extension shows up when I type `\dx` in the `psql` console. However, the functions that this extension provides (such as `uuid_generate_v4`) do NOT show up when I type `\df`, and so any attempt to use the functions that should be added fails.

When I take the SQL from the ActiveRecord migration and copy+paste it into the `psql` console directly, everything works as expected - extension is added, and functions are available.

#### Here is my migration code:

```rb
class EnableUuidOssp < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.0]
  def up
    enable_extension "uuid-ossp"
  end

  def down
    disable_extension "uuid-ossp"
  end
end
```

Here is the output:

```
$ bundle exec rake db:migrate
== 20190308113821 EnableUuidOssp: migrating ==============================
-- enable_extension("uuid-ossp")
   -> 0.0075s
== 20190308113821 EnableUuidOssp: migrated (0.0076s) =====================
```

^ this all appears to run successfully, but no functions are enabled. Which means future SQL that includes statements such as `... SET uuid = uuid_generate_v4() ...` fail with the this error `HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.`

#### What does work

Going directly into `psql` and typing:

```
CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
```

^ This installs the extension and makes the functions avaiable.

#### And yet, what doesn't work

Okay, so if I take the above SQL and rewrite my migration this way:

```rb
  ...

  def up
    execute <<~SQL
      CREATE EXTENSION IF NOT EXISTS "uuid-ossp";
    SQL
  end

  ...
```

^ this migration will run without error, yet it will still not make the functions available.

So, the same copy+paste SQL that works in `psql` doesn't work via the ActiveRecord `execute` method, which really puzzles me. I'm not sure what piece I'm missing that's causing this to fail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume that the schema where the extension is installed is not on your `search_path`.

You can see that schema with

```
\dx "uuid-ossp"
```

Try to qualify the functions with the schema, like in `public.uuid_generate_v4()`.

Comment: Silly me -- thanks. Was totally working, but when I typed `\df` I wasn't specifying the schema, so I only thought the functions weren't available. Between that and mixing up several different versions of this migration I wasn't both installing the extension correctly AND looking at the resulting functions on the proper schema, at the same time.

Comment: Thanks for the `public.uuid_generate_v4()` tip!